# DjangoRest Serializer возвращает пустой объект

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Когда я пытаюсь сериализовать объект возвращается пустая строка

model.py

```
class Product (models.Model):
   id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True) 
   name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, default='')
   price = models.IntegerField()
   count_of_flowers = models.IntegerField()
   type = models.ForeignKey('Type')
   box_type = models.ForeignKey('Box', blank=True)
   flowers_color = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, default='')

class Type(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, default='')

class Box(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, default='')
```

Serializer.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from models import Product, Type, Box

class BoxSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    class Meta: 
        model = Box
        field = ('name')

class TypeSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    class Meta: 
        model = Type
        field = ('name')


class ProductSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
   boxes = BoxSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
   types = TypeSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)   
   class Meta:
            model = Product
            fields = ('id','name','price','count_of_flowers','boxes','types''flowers_color')
```

Далее когда я через view или через shell пытаюсь получить json получаю пустую строку. 
Пытался так же убирать зависимости от Box и Type и комментить соотв. строки - результат тот же

Comment: Добавьте еще код ,где вы получаете данные из ProductSerializer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать serializers.ModelSerializer вместо serializers.Serializer. Иначе у вас получается serializer совсем без полей, вот и не возваращает ничего.

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from models import Product, Type, Box

class BoxSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta: 
        model = Box
        fields = ('name')

class TypeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta: 
        model = Type
        fields = ('name')


class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    boxes = BoxSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    types = TypeSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'price', 'count_of_flowers', 'boxes', 'types', 'flowers_color')
```

Comment: Если вообще убрать параметр fields, тогда вернутся все поля.